# How to share methods between ActionMailers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionmailer, helper

I have two mailers:

```
class Mailer1 < ActionMailer::Base
  def mail
    if check_something?
    end
  end

  private

  def check_something?
  end
end


class Mailer2 < ActionMailer::Base
  def another_mail
    if check_something?
    end
  end

  private

  def check_something?
  end
end
```

(I understand I can pull in view helpers for the actual mail templates, but how can I make it work for controller-type "helper" methods - as ActionMailers derive from Abstract Controller these days.)

So, where can I declare check_something?, and how can I make it accessible to both my mailers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a base class, like you get by default with ApplicationController for your http controllers:

```
class AppMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  protected
  def check_something?
  end
end

class Mailer1 < AppMailer
  def mail
    if check_something?
    end
  end
end


class Mailer2 < AppMailer
  def another_mail
    if check_something?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I also can't see any other way. This will do fine then. Thanks.